# Dictionary update sequence error on upgrading with contrib.auth.views to Django 1.7

Tags: python, django

I'm migrating a Django 1.6 project to Django 1.7 and am running into a problem with django.contrib.auth.views. I can't load my home page which is also the login page. The following code works fine in Django 1.6.

In the urls.py file I import like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout
```

and do this:

```
url(r'^$', login, {'template_name': 'splash.html', 'extra_context': {'next': '/journal'}}, name='splash'),
```

It works fine under 1.6, but running under Django 1.7 I get:

```
ValueError at /
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 2 is required
```

I checked the documentation of 1.7 and see nothing that would require me to change the syntax of the call, but it's not working.

This is the traceback:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/

Django Version: 1.7.10
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'timezone_field',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'haystack',
 'endless_pagination',
 'djangobower',
 'journal')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'journal.middleware.TimezoneMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/f/virt_env/journal_17_27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  137.                 response = response.render()
File "/Users/f/virt_env/journal_17_27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  103.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/Users/f/virt_env/journal_17_27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  79.         context = self.resolve_context(self.context_data)
File "/Users/f/virt_env/journal_17_27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in resolve_context
  156.         return RequestContext(self._request, context, current_app=self._current_app)
File "/Users/f/virt_env/journal_17_27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/context.py" in __init__
  209.             updates.update(processor(request))

Exception Type: ValueError at /
Exception Value: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 2 is required
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't caused by anything in your view, but by one of your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`. One of them is returning invalid value (most probably some iterable of tuples instead of dict).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Indeed it was a problem with the context processors. I was using login_required decorator on them which worked in 1.6 for some reason but not in 1.7. I rewrote the context processors to use the user.is_authenticated() instead, returning an empty dictionary if it failed.